# unable to view designer of windows form added as existing item

Tags: c#

I have added a windows form to my visual studio 2013 project by using the option "Add an existing item". I only add the *.cs file in the project and the rest of files (*.Designer.cs, *.resx) are generated automatically.
I can view the code but i m unable to view designer of this form. (i cant edit form by using toolbox).
Any solution for this..??
Thanks

Comment: That is sometimes due to a compile error...

Comment: you also need to add the .designer and .resx files. If they were generated your form will be empty now... A windows form is build up from these 3 files.

Answer (score 1):

Open the project file (yourproject.csproj) in your favorite text editor.

Ensure that the entry that references the form in the project has a subtype of "Form".

Steps:
Locate the line that includes said form in the project.

```
<Compile Include="Forms\Login.cs" />
```

Change to:

```
<Compile Include="Forms\Login.cs" >
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Save the csproj file and open the project/solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to this is:

- Add the windows form files (.cs, .designer.cs and .resx) to a
  directory in your solution, using windows explorer.
- In the VS solution explorer make sure you set the 'Show all files' option.
- Refresh the solution explorer using the refresh button.
- Right click the file (which should already been recognized as windows form) and choose 'Include in project'

Comment: The problem is still there.. The windows form file is recognized as C# class and i m unable to view its designer...

Comment: are you sure the .designer and .resx file are unedited by hand? Will they open in the Original solution that was used to build the form?

Comment: Any news? Does the form load in the original solution?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.. All u need is to add the .cs file of the windows form (.designer.cs and .resx files will be added automatically). then close your solution and reopen it after a while. Your .cs file will be recognized as windows form by visual studio...